# Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'UINavigationController?'

Tags: swift, xcode6

I can't solve the error in AppDelegate.swift.

I got a message 'Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'UINavigationController?'

any one give me advice?

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    let alarmViewController = AlarmViewController(style: .Plain)
    let recorderViewController = RecorderViewController()
    let playViewController = PlayViewController()

    let tabController1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: recorderViewController)
    tabController1?.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Recorder", image: UIImage(named: "tabbar_microphone"), tag: 1)

    let tabController2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: playViewController)
    tabController2?.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Cheer me up!", image: UIImage(named: "tabbar_play"), tag: 2)

    let tabController3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: alarmViewController!)
    tabController3?.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Alarm", image: UIImage(named: "tabbar_alarm"), tag: 3)

    ******* here's a place I got the message 'Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'UINavigationController?' *******
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [tabController1, tabController2, tabController3]

    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tabControllerX`s are all optionals (as you seem to realise, as you reference them all as `?` when assigning the `UITabBarItem`s) so you need to unwrap them. Simplest way, given how you've structured it, is simply to change the line

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = [tabController1!, tabController2!, tabController3!]
// Unwrap tabControllers
```

I would have done it differently, as I don't like having optionals hanging around in my logic not knowing whether they are nil or not, something like

```
if let tabController1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: recorderViewController)
    // Now you know it's a tabController!
    tabController1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Recorder", image: UIImage(named: "tabbar_microphone"), tag: 1) 
    // ...
} else {
    // what are you going to do if it's nil?
}
```